# Read from multiple Raspberry Pi Pico simultaneously

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart, raspberry-pi-pico

There are 3 Raspberry Pi Pico peripherals and 1 Raspberry Pi 4 hub. All Raspberry Pi Pico send data to Raspberry Pi 4 over Bluetooth Low Energy. I am able to get them to send individually but not all at the same time.

How to modify the UART service/characteristic values to make it unique for all Raspberry Pi Pico to send simultaneously? All Raspberry Pi Pico have `uart_tx='6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'`. Should this value be unique and if so, how do I assign it? If not, how do I read data? Is it possible by MAC address?

Code:

```
import os
import psutil
import BLE_GATT

from time import sleep
from gi.repository import GLib


# ubit_address = ['xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx', 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx']
uart_rx = '6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'
uart_tx = '6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e'

#os.system("pkill -9 -f ble_pi_pico.py")
for index, value in enumerate(ubit_address):
    os.system("bluetoothctl connect "+value) # to connect to BLE with MAC Address
    sleep(1)


def notify_handler(value):
    print(f"Distance/ Temp: {bytes(value).decode('UTF-8')}")


for index1, value1 in enumerate(ubit_address):
    ubit = BLE_GATT.Central(value1)
    ubit.connect()
    ubit.on_value_change(uart_tx, notify_handler)
    ubit.wait_for_notifications()
```

[image]